# Instantiating view controller from AppDelegate - view controller code runs but doesn't show on screen

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, google-signin, appdelegate

This is the code in my `AppDelegate` that is meant to run after a user successfully authenticates with Google:

```
func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {
        print("User Email: \(user.profile.email ?? "No Email")")
        
        let mainStoryboard:UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let homeViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: Constants.Storyboard.tabBarController)
        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        self.window?.rootViewController = homeViewController
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
```

I can tell by the console that the code in my `homeViewController` is being run after the user authenticates. **However, the `homeViewController` is not being shown on screen.** Is there something else I need to add? Perhaps in the `SceneDelegate`?

Any guidance is much appreciated!

Comment: What is homeViewController?  How could the compiler tell which one you are talking about?  window?  Does AppDelegate have a variable for that?

Comment: It doesn't sound like you have disabled `SceneDelegate`.